Long time commiting file Intellij IDEA
I'm have one update file in project. But it's very long time updated. Antivirus windows deactivated. What could be the problem? Intellij IDEA Community.
I'm try off my antivirus and reload Intellij IDEA. But it's not help this situation. Reload Intellij IDEA more times. it didn't work out. What do I need to do to make it work?
Git log -
16:37:26.902: [AccountingSystem] /usr/bin/git -c credential.helper= -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false add --ignore-errors -A -f -- src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@restart/hooks/useDebouncedState/package.json src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/es-abstract/2020/Number/equal.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@restart/hooks/cjs/useRefWithInitialValueFactory.d.ts src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/core-js/es/object/assign.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/core-js/modules/esnext.iterator.flat-map.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@babel/polyfill/node_modules/core-js/modules/_math-log1p.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/tapable/lib/SyncHook.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/make-dir/node_modules/semver/README.md src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/npm/node_modules/.bin/semver src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/regenerate-unicode-properties/Script/Javanese.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/react-bootstrap/cjs/TabContent.d.ts src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/neo-async/applyEach.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/terser/lib/equivalent-to.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/caniuse-lite/data/regions/alt-na.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/npm/node_modules/safer-buffer/Readme.md src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-install-checks/index.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/core-js/es/math/acosh.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@babel/polyfill/node_modules/core-js/library/fn/string/iterator.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/core-js/es/instance/map.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/caniuse-lite/data/features/once-event-listener.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@babel/polyfill/node_modules/core-js/es7/map.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/npm/man/man1/npm-prefix.1 src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@babel/polyfill/node_modules/core-js/fn/string/virtual/link.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@restart/hooks/esm/useMountEffect.d.ts src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/es-abstract/2019/HasProperty.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/pulse-till-done.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/_border-radius.scss src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@babel/polyfill/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es6.weak-set.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@types/json-schema/index.d.ts src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/npm/node_modules/spdx-expression-parse/LICENSE src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/bin.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/RuntimeRequirementsDependency.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/npm/node_modules/ansi-regex/index.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/npm/node_modules/normalize-package-data/lib/safe_format.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/core-js/features/array/virtual/to-sorted.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/caniuse-lite/data/regions/BF.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-catch-binding/lib/index.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@jridgewell/trace-mapping/LICENSE src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/wrapRegExp.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/Col.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/regenerate-unicode-properties/Script_Extensions/Bamum.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/move-file/package.json src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/npm/node_modules/cacache/lib/put.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@restart/ui/cjs/DropdownItem.d.ts src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/caniuse-lite/data/features/css-animation.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/core-js/es/array/some.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@types/node/repl.d.ts src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/core-js/actual/string/fontsize.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/ajv/lib/dot/coerce.def src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/core-js/modules/es.regexp.constructor.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/react-bootstrap/cjs/AbstractModalHeader.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@babel/polyfill/node_modules/core-js/modules/_to-object.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_breadcrumb.scss src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/npm/node_modules/http-proxy-agent/dist/agent.d.ts src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/audit-error.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/regjsgen/LICENSE-MIT.txt src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/core-js/es/instance/index-of.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@webassemblyjs/wasm-parser/LICENSE src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/get-intrinsic/.nycrc src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/writeOnlyError.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/has-bigints/CHANGELOG.md src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/neo-async/any.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/dom-helpers/cjs/camelize.d.ts src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/shebang-command/index.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/npm/node_modules/libnpmversion/lib/commit.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/fast-deep-equal/index.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/dom-helpers/esm/transitionEnd.d.ts src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/webpack/lib/runtime/CompatGetDefaultExportRuntimeModule.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-modules-umd/package.json src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/es-abstract/2018/SameValue.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-normalize-package-bin/test/array.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/import-local/node_modules/locate-path/readme.md src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/react-bootstrap/cjs/Overlay.d.ts src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/regenerate-unicode-properties/Script_Extensions/Old_Persian.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/generated/virtual-types.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@babel/polyfill/node_modules/core-js/modules/_string-context.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/core-js/modules/esnext.map.reduce.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/caniuse-lite/data/regions/PF.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/npm/node_modules/binary-extensions/package.json src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/regenerate-unicode-properties/Script/Saurashtra.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/react-transition-group/esm/SwitchTransition.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/NavbarBrand.d.ts src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/core-js/internals/to-positive-integer.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@restart/ui/NavItem/package.json src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/webpack/lib/sharing/ConsumeSharedModule.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/caniuse-lite/data/regions/CX.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/react-hook-form/dist/utils/isEmptyObject.d.ts src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/caniuse-lite/data/features/css-reflections.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/prop-types/README.md src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/es-abstract/2018/ToDateString.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/bin/node-which src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@babel/polyfill/node_modules/core-js/fn/date/index.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@babel/polyfill/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es7.reflect.get-own-metadata-keys.js

16:37:27.717: [AccountingSystem] /usr/bin/git -c credential.helper= -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false add --ignore-errors -A -f -- src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/source-map-js/lib/array-set.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/react-bootstrap/DropdownButton/package.json src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@webassemblyjs/ast/lib/traverse.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@babel/polyfill/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es6.parse-int.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/webpack-merge/dist/unique.js.map src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/jquery/src/var/arr.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@babel/polyfill/node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.math.asinh.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/npm/node_modules/ansicolors/LICENSE src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/npm/node_modules/brace-expansion/LICENSE src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/core-js/features/promise/try.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/neo-async/forEachSeries.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/react-bootstrap/cjs/ModalDialog.d.ts src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/dom-helpers/querySelectorAll/package.json src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/neo-async/createLogger.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/es-abstract/2016/IteratorClose.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/caniuse-lite/data/features/resizeobserver.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/core-js/features/array/virtual/splice.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/npm/node_modules/iconv-lite/encodings/dbcs-data.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/dom-helpers/cjs/index.d.ts src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/color-convert/README.md src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/es-abstract/2017/GetMethod.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/caniuse-lite/dist/unpacker/browserVersions.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/npm/docs/output/commands/npm.html src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@babel/polyfill/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es6.reflect.delete-property.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/core-js/modules/es.function.has-instance.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@babel/polyfill/node_modules/core-js/library/fn/array/reduce-right.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/webpack-merge/package.json src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/caniuse-lite/data/features/async-functions.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/BootstrapModalManager.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/regenerate-unicode-properties/Script_Extensions/Khmer.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/caniuse-lite/data/features/css-text-justify.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-class-static-block/package.json src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/ajv/lib/compile/error_classes.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/p-limit/readme.md src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/object-keys/isArguments.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/react-is/index.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/jquery/src/traversing/var/siblings.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/caniuse-lite/data/regions/GH.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/esm/dom-utils/getWindow.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/npm/node_modules/semver/functions/major.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/commander/typings/index.d.ts src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@babel/template/lib/populate.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@restart/ui/cjs/TabContext.d.ts src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/core-js/stable/object/get-own-property-descriptor.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/es-abstract/2017/ToUint8Clamp.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/caniuse-lite/data/features/font-smooth.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/node-environment-flags/polyfill.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@babel/polyfill/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/_is-integer.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/es-abstract/2015/CreateDataProperty.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/core-js/features/array/virtual/group-by-to-map.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/npm/node_modules/colors/safe.d.ts src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/core-js/modules/es.array-buffer.is-view.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/react-transition-group/dist/react-transition-group.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/es-abstract/2019/QuoteJSONString.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/caniuse-lite/data/features/scrollintoviewifneeded.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/npm/node_modules/https-proxy-agent/package.json src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/es-abstract/2021/SplitMatch.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@babel/polyfill/node_modules/core-js/modules/_has.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@babel/polyfill/node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.array.of.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/pify/license src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@babel/polyfill/node_modules/core-js/modules/core.get-iterator.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/react-hook-form/dist/utils/stringToPath.d.ts.map src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-logical-assignment-operators/README.md src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/core-js/modules/es.symbol.match.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/is-string/LICENSE src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/core-js/es/object/is-extensible.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/core-js/modules/esnext.map.update.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/rechoir/lib/register.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/shallow-clone/index.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/path-parse/LICENSE src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/es-abstract/helpers/DefineOwnProperty.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/core-js/proposals/object-values-entries.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/npm/node_modules/semver/functions/coerce.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/npm/man/man1/npm-edit.1 src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@babel/polyfill/node_modules/core-js/package.json src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/react-bootstrap/Carousel/package.json src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/core-js/features/set/index.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@restart/hooks/cjs/useUpdateEffect.d.ts src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/core-js/es/number/is-nan.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/core-js/stable/string/virtual/trim-right.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator/README.md src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/core-js/modules/es.typed-array.from.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/rechoir/LICENSE src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/cjs/popper-base.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/picocolors/picocolors.browser.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/babel-loader/node_modules/pkg-dir/index.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/regenerate-unicode-properties/Script/Mahajani.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/npm/node_modules/is-fullwidth-code-point/readme.md src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/helpers/deep-array.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/core-js/es/string/small.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/core-js/internals/array-unique-by.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/@babel/polyfill/node_modules/core-js/modules/es7.string.trim-right.js src/main/resources/templates/node_modules/dom-helpers/cjs/position.d.ts


What exactly are you trying to do in idea? I see it's adding bunch of files in the git

I'm add folder node_modules in commit. Anyway so long but it solved problem. About 15 minuts.

Is solved. My bed. I don't add folder node_modules in git. But anyway process commiting so long.

